# How to add a clickable mail address in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

For our chatbot, we were wondering if it's possible to add a clickable link (mail address). We want to add a clickable mail address which opens a new window (the email program). 
Opening a clickable link (webpage) is possible but we haven't reached it to do the same with the mail program.

Kind regards,

Guido Plettenberg

Answer (score 0):

You can use the markdown syntax for this

```
[I'm an inline-style link](mailto:xyz@foobar.com?subject=[stackoverflow]subject)
```

Comment: Hi Nico, 
Thank you for your answer. Is there a possibility to make a clickable link (mail address) in the default section of Dialogflow? I’m interested in this because I’m trying to construct a chatbot that doesn’t use Google Assistant.
 
Kind regards,
 
Guido Plettenberg